# Does English contain accented letters?

Tags: american-english, american-accent, accent

Does English contain accented letters?  Is there a standard list of accented letters that are used in the English language?

In my application I'm currently allowing the characters `a-z` and `áéóúíý äëöüïÿ '-`.  The reason I'm allowing `'-` as well is because some people names contain them.

Comment: Are English names the only inputs you are considering?

Comment: Here are two good starting points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic, http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/frank/kiss/kiss3.htm.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *accents/diacritics*, which aren't really a feature of English ***at all***. So it's entirely subjective which particular symbols *some* people might accept as "valid in English" (imho, ***none***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about cliché? coöperate? Or, since OP asks about names, Noël? Renée? The diacritics are not essential, but they are used here and there - and we generally concede nominees the right to spell their names in any way they choose.

Comment: @StoneyB: I occasionally write *clichéed*, but rarely *cliché* unless it just happens to be in cut&pasted text. As to *coöperate*, I'd normally go to the trouble of editing it to *cooperate* even if it *was* in some cut&pasted text, because I think it's slightly ridiculous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that at worst, this question is on topic indirectly and at best, it is on topic.. well... indirectly.  Because people who read English will read words that have diacritics.  It has become a small world, after all.  The OP properly selected the answer that indicates English doesn't have accented letters which is basically your point. And the two answers are good. Note: I agreed with you to close at first, but then retracted after reading the answers.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: Point taken. I said myself *diacritics aren't **really** a feature of English*, and StoneyB proposed some counterexamples, so clearly the issue itself is "debatable", and thus at the very least *indirectly* related to learning English. The more so since *some* learners are familiar with diacritics used in their native language, which *some* Anglophones faithfully replicate in foreign words "adopted" into English. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)#English) says grave & diaeresis are the only diacritics native to English (but are considered archaic).

Comment: I voted to reopen. The proper answer, which was provided and accepted, addresses both concerns which prompted the closing: (1) The answer is not a subjective list of accepted accents and (2) Standard English doesn't *inherently* have any accented letters. (We don't have to answer questions exactly as asked.)  Other points about unicode, loanwords, and cultural references (Choster's ref to The New Yorker) provide valuable or interesting related information. I think the answers given make this clear and valuable.

Comment: I have changed the wording of the question to fit more properly with the answers. The question should be unequivocal now.

Comment: Off topic here - but what will you do if somebody types a character that's not on your list?  Will you tell them their name is invalid?

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). One example: [Jennifer 8. Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_8._Lee)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could count accents on imported words (café, resumé, piñata). Some names also include accents (Zoë, Brontë, Beyoncé). Then there's the rare case of using accents and umlauts over certain vowels (naïve, coöperation) - this is a [non-standard convention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cooperate%2Cco%C3%B6perate&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccooperate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cco%C3%B6perate%3B%2Cc0) not used by the majority of English speakers.

It's rare to see accents or diacritics in modern English as anything other than a stylistic typographical choice. A good example of this is [Häagen-Dazs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A4agen-Dazs) ice cream, whose Bronx, NY creators put a superfluous umlaut in the name to add a European flair.

Many other languages with Latin alphabets use umlauts and other diacritics. 
Examples from the original question are missing ñ, ø, vowels with macron (top bar ā, ī etc) or circumflex (â,ê etc) as well as many others.

That gets to the key point of the question, which is that you should be asking about the Extended Latin alphabet - not "English."

Assuming by "application" you mean software, you should look into how Unicode characters work, and what localization options are provided by the platform you're developing for. This is a complicated topic that goes well beyond just the language, and is better suited to asking at StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for saving me. I was ready to answer, no, until I read your excellent examples of English words with accents. A brief enrichment - in the past, accents were omitted because typewriters didn't include those keys. Word processors made the inclusion of accentuated letters much easier, so accented letters are coming back into vogue.

Answer (score 5):

English traditionally uses very few diacritical marks compared to other European languages.

**English employs a huge number of loanwords**, however, so to provide enough characters to represent all commonly used English words, you may as well use the entire [Latin-1 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). We would not want, for example, to deprive people of proper orthography for their

- ångströms
- arrastãos
- daïses
- entrepôts
- façades
- fêtes
- Māori
- piñatas

Certain romanization systems require still further characters. For example, the capital of North Korea should technically be rendered as *P'yŏngyang* and the lingua franca of Malawi is technically *Chicheŵa*.

---

As you can see, where diacritics remain in use, they are mostly retained from their original languages, and are especially retained where they help avoid confusion with another word. For example, *façade* is fading in favor of *facade*, but *maté* and *résumé* are still going strong.

Traditionally, the *diaresis* (¨) is used to indicate that two adjacent vowels should be pronounced separately instead of as a dipthong, as in *naïve*. This usage has been fading fast, with *The New Yorker* among the few [famously clinging](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2012/04/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis.html) to the old convention.

Otherwise, diacritics are largely found in poetry as scansion markers. Most commonly, the grave accent (`) indicates that a vowel should be pronounced where it is ordinarily suppressed; for example, *blessèd* and *learnèd* have two syllables whereas *blessed* and *learned* have one, but such examples are only really found in poetry. Similarly, the acute accent (´) indicates which syllable should receive stress, the [breve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve) (˘) shortens a syllable, and the [macron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron) (¯) lengthens it, but these are almost never encountered elsewhere outside of loanwords.

Comment: I don't deny people the right to use words like *ångströms* if they're writing in their native language, but I don't endorse it if they're writing in *English*.

Answer (score 2):

In English and a couple of other languages, when two vowels occur in adjacent syllables, with no intervening consonant, you may place two dots over the second to indicate that this is not a diphthong.  So you may write *coöperate*, *daïs*, *preëmptive*, *reëlect* and a handful of others.  My favourite is *skiïng*.

This is English.  This is nothing to do with whether a word is introduced from a foreign language.  So it is entirely incorrect to say that English has no accented letters.  It is, of course, optional; but one publication for which this is the "house style" is [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/).

Of course, if you include introduced words, then there are dozens, possibly hundreds.  *Café*, *fiancé*, *hāngi*, *naïve* and *ångström* are the obvious ones for me.

Comment: Adopting diacritics as a stylistic convention (an imported practice itself) is very different from them being a fundamental part of the language. In other languages, 'ö' and 'o' are separate characters. Among the 26 letters of modern English none have accents. Google Ngrams for all examples above show 100% without umlauts - the other versions aren't even found. While "you may," nobody does. All this aside, the question was fundamentally a misunderstanding about the extended Latin alphabet used in a programming context. It really didn't belong on this site.

Comment: @mc01 - it's not true that "nobody does", which is why I cited The New Yorker as an example.  I have seen all of the words that I listed, written as I wrote them here.  It is a feature of English, unless you want to limit the word "English" to mean the particular variety that you yourself write.  So your argument in the comment here is as incorrect as your answer.

Comment: Edited my answer above. I concede this exists & I've seen it too, but this remains a rare, non-standard, stylistic choice. I amend my comment to say "practically nobody"  has used this convention for several decades. Even the New Yorker admits to being an obstinate, holdout edge case.
My goal was to address the intent of the OP's question (how to account for accents & diacritics in software) without getting bogged down in minutiae that doesn't help solve the problem. You are correct, but I didn't see value in burying the key point among a laundry list of qualifying fringe examples. Cheers ~